# JSP&Spring: How can I pass one parameter using JSP EL with submit button?

Tags: spring, jsp

I'm trying to pass one parameter from a jsp page to Spring controller file.
However, I fail and fail again.

When I put just real data of database like a, b, c... instead of "${deleteList['user_id']}", my codes works well.

I have no idea. 
I'd be appriciated if I can get your answer.

```
<table border="0">
<c:forEach items="${deleteList}" var="deleteList">
    <tr><td align="right">ID:</td><td>${deleteList.user_id}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>                
</table> <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/delete" method="get"> <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="${deleteList['user_id']}" />

<input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Delete" />
```

---

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", params="confirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String deleteConfirm(Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {

            String user_id=req.getParameter("user_id");

              UmsDAO dao=sqlSession.getMapper(UmsDAO.class);
              ArrayList<UVO> uvo = dao.deleteList(user_id);        
              model.addAttribute("deleteList", uvo);

    return "user/deleteConfirm";
  }
```

---

```
<c:forEach items="${deleteList}" var="deleteList">
    <tr><td align="right">ID:</td><td>${deleteList.user_id}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Please inspect hidden input element in a browser, what values you can see?

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyurt I solved this problem with session. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending any value in user_id..

```
     <tr><td align="right">ID:</td><td>${deleteList.user_id}</td>

<td> from  this try once.. you will get specific value what you want</td>
</tr>
```

Instead of using form every time use anchor tag and send value in partameter

Comment: why do you think having he value in the <td> tag will solve OP problem?

Comment: We are showing multiple userid so we have to send only one userid not all on which we have to do operation

Comment: I dont think OP is sending multiple userId,

Comment: To SpringLearner, Navnath Adsul: I solved the problem with session. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
use HttpSession

---

**For example:**

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", params = "confirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteConfirm(Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
String user_id = (String) session.getAttribute("user_id");

UmsDAO dao = sqlSession.getMapper(UmsDAO.class);
ArrayList<UVO> uvo = dao.deleteList(user_id);
model.addAttribute("deleteList", uvo);

return "user/deleteConfirm";
```

}